# Auto mount veracrypt partition after login - without root password

Tags: linux, debian, passwords, sudoers, veracrypt

I'm working on a debian-based linux machine (MX linux), trying to automate the mount process for a veracrypt encrypted partition, right after user login - and it won't work and i don'k know what to do anymore.

After logging in, i want to be asked for the veracrypt password for the partition - and nothing else. No `root` or `sudo` password, nothing like that.

**My setup:**

**1)** I've created this little shell script, that would launch veracrypt, ask for the password and provide the crypted partition as a device in `/dev/mapper/veracrypt1`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo veracrypt --filesystem=none --mount /dev/nvme0n1p8 /media/Data
```

AFAIK, the second parameter for the `--mount` option is skipped due to `--filesystem=none` - and that's okay, because next:

**2)** This line in `/etc/fstab` will then mount this device with read and write access:

```
/dev/mapper/veracrypt1 /media/Username/Data auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,discard 0 0
```

...and that's working as intended - but besides the veracrypt password, i need to enter the sudo/root password multiple times in the process. This is what i want to get rid of.

So i did:

**3)** Using `/etc/fstab`, the mount is using `udisks2`. The popup asking for root credentials shows, that `org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system` is the method used here. This has a polkit-policy on my pc, located in: `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.UDisks2.policy`

In this file, the method is listed - and below it, there is the authorisation configuration in the three items `allow_any`, `allow_inactive` and `allow_active`. I set them all to `yes` and now, if `/etc/fstab` mounts `/dev/mapper/veracrypt1`, no root password is needed.

But i still need to enter the root password when launching my shell script above. So...

**4)** I used `visudo` and entered this, to allow commands without a password.

```
Username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mount, /bin/mount, /usr/bin/veracrypt, /home/Username/mount_vc.sh
```

I wasn't sure what exactly i need there, so i put in both `mount` commands and `veracrypt`. I even added the shell script right there, just in case it might help. It didn't.

*(The real sudoers file contains some further commands i want to use without password, so this is just the relevant part.)*

**5)** Finally, i went to the startup configuration of my system and added an entry that points to the shell script and runs it after user login.

**In theory, it should be fine. In real world, it does nothing.**

The script is called after login. I tried entering a line that would `touch` a file in my home directory. This file has been created. But the veracrypt command didn't work.

Calling the shell script manually works, but still needs the root password. I've located `veracrypt` using `which`, that's the path i entered in `/etc/sudoers`. It doesn't work.

As mentioned above, i've other commands in this sudoers-line - and they work. Other commands listed there can be called without sudo/root password. Veracrypt doesn't.

"Something" is not working correct, but after spending hours on this, i can't figure out what.

**How can i run my script at login, launching the `veracrypt` command automatically - without needing a sudo/root passwort to start the command?**

*Edit, to clarify:*

If i login, **nothing** happens. No veracrypt is launched, nothing is asking me for root password - nothing happens at all.

If i start the script manually, i'm first asked for the password, then veracrypt launches. If i enter the crypt-password there, the partition is mounted correct.

**Edit, my last attempt:**

I've wondered about the `sudo` in my shell script. Having my `/etc/sudoers` modified, i removed the `sudo` and tried without. This happens after login:

First, veracrypt started! Without another prompt, i could enter my veracrypt password for the partition.

But then, after entering the veracrypt password, a popup requires me to enter the root password. Veracrypt is waiting in the background, trying to mount the partition - but can't do until i enter the root pw.

I'm out of ideas and somewhat frustrated - what in hell do i have to put in my `sudoers`, to keep my system shutting up and not asking for root permissions for this command?!

*Fun fact: I've had this working on another machine. It doesn't exist anymore, but somehow i've got this working. Now, i have no clue whats wrong.*

**Edit: Workaround, kind of:**

What does work, of course: I've added my User to the `sudo` group.

Everything works fine now, but i'm not very happy with this solution. Would be great to find another way, to get rid of the password prompts - without being in the `sudo` group.